# Why can't I update the contents of my UIScrollView using NSOperationQueue / NSOperationInvocation?

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton, uiimage, nsoperationqueue

I think I remember something about UI being updated on the main thread, could be the explanation, however my issue is that I have a UIScrollView with 1000+ images in it, and I wrote a routine that quickly will toggle the images visible in the view to show their real image, and when out of visible view, they switch to a placeholder image. All the offscreen images share the same placeholder, greatly reducing memory load.

I wrote two methods that toggle the next few tiles of the view on/off, and are kicked off if you have scrolled enough in a certain direction. The scrolling is detected via the UIScrollViewDelegate callback method scrollViewDidScroll.

This strategy works fine, but the scrollview scrolling is a little jittery on slow devices (iPad 1). I wanted to increase performance, so I thought I could change the code so that the two methods that update the scrollview contents were NSOperationInvocation, added to an NSOperationQueue.

However, when I do this, even with priority set to VeryHigh, the routines to not update the UI even though they seem to be called, and the queue does grow, when scrolling. The observed behavior is that the images retain their placeholder images and do not switch on.

Why doesn't this work?

Code for the NSOperationInvocation:

```
    ImageThumbView *thumb = [boardThumbsArray objectAtIndex:lowestLoadedThumbTag - i];
    [loadedThumbsArray addObject:thumb];
    [thumb showThumbImage];
```

ImageThumbView is a UIButton Subclass

```
    - (void)showThumbImage {

if (thumbImagePath != nil) {
    thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thumbImagePath]]];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Cannot show thumb image: thumbImagePath is nil");
}

[self setBackgroundImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Look at Apple's "PhotoScroller" sample code. You should not be having 1000 views as subviews of scrollview. Recycle the ones that are no longer visible.

Also look at WWDC 2010 "Designing apps with scrollview" video. That explains the photoscroller sample code

Thanks